# Difference in the value received in this.props when using mapStateToProps (react-redux) vs store.getState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am facing an issue in my code base so I have made a sample code to demonstrate the issue.

link for the codesandbox [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/20xwy)

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { handleDataInit, handlePageChange, handleDataAdded } from './appDataAction';


import First from './First';
import Second from './Second';

import { reduxStore } from "./store";


class App extends Component {
  handleChange = (pageNumber, pageTitle) => {
    let data = {
      val1: "val1",
      val2: "val2",
      val3: "val3"
    }

    this.props.handleDataAdded(data);

    console.log("app Data", this.props.appData);
    console.log('app data in redux store ', reduxStore.getState().appData);

    this.props.handlePageChange({ pageNumber, pageTitle });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <button onClick={() => this.handleChange(1, "first_page")}>1</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleChange(2, "second_page")}>2</button>
        {
          this.props.appData.pageNumber === 1 ?
            <First />
            :
            <Second />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('map state to props state value is ', state);
  return ({
    appData: state && state.appData
  })
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return ({
    handleDataInit: (data) => dispatch(handleDataInit(data)),
    handlePageChange: (newPage) => dispatch(handlePageChange(newPage)),
    handleDataAdded: (data) => dispatch(handleDataAdded(data))
  })
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

screenshot for the two console.log
browser console log:
[image]

appDataAction.js

```
export const handleDataInit = (data) => {
    return ({
        type: "data_init",
        payload: data
    });
}

export const handlePageChange = (newPage) => {
    return ({
        type: "page_change",
        payload: newPage
    });
}

export const handleDataAdded = (data) => {
    return ({
        type: "data_added",
        payload: data
    });
}
```

appDataReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
    pageNumber: 1,
    pageTitle: "first_page",
}

export const appDataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "data_init":
            if (Object.keys(state).length > 2) {
                return state
            }
            else {
                let newState = Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
                // console.log("new state in init ", newState);
                return newState;
            }

        case "page_change":
            // console.log('action.payload', action.payload);
            let newState2 = {
                ...state,
                pageNumber: action.payload.pageNumber,
                pageTitle: action.payload.pageTitle
            }
            // console.log('new state is ', newState2);
            return newState2;

        case "data_added":
            let newState3 = Object.assign({}, state, action.payload);
            // console.log("new state in data added ", newState3);
            return newState3;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

From react-redux documentation

**The first argument to a mapStateToProps function is the entire Redux store state (the same value returned by a call to store.getState()).**

can somebody explain why there is difference in the two console's.
I have debugged and found out that after return from reducer mapStateToProps is called and it gets the updated value of state
then why is this.props.appData is not up to date in the handleChange function.

I believe it could be something related to dirty state but if it is proper for getState() in the function it should be for this.props.appData too.

[image]

Comment: You might want to put that into a codesandbox or something we can easily try ourselves. This is a lot of code to read without being able to interact with it.

Comment: done provided a link for sandbox [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/20xwy)

Answer (score 0):

> `console.log("app Data", this.props.appData);`

The `handleChange` clearly has a Javascript [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over the `this.props` object and thus the current `this.props.appData` value ***at the time*** that `handleChange` was invoked. This `this.props.appData` value will not ever be a different value during the life of the execution of the `handleChange` callback no matter how many state updates are dispatched. `handleChange` needs to complete and return, and then React will process any enqueued state updates/etc, and trigger a component rerender wherein the `this.props.appData` will be the current value from the store.

> `console.log('app data in redux store ', reduxStore.getState().appData);`

`reduxStore.getState` accesses the store and gets the current value of the state at the time that it is called. Keep in mind that a Redux store exists in normal Javascript, outside Reactland. It's the `react-redux` library that provides the "glue" between the two and allows React to rerender when the store updates.

It is generally not recommended to call `store.getState` directly in React components. Use the `connect` Higher Order Component or the newer `useSelector` hook to subscribe a React component to Redux state updates.